# Configuring GKE ingress to allow only Google requests (Cloud Tasks)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-tasks, gke-networking

I have a public HTTP API service running in a GKE and am considering using Cloud Tasks with an HTTP target endpoint. I know that securing those via eg oidc tokens is the preferred way but I’m wondering anyway if it would be possible to somehow allow access to this route (set of routes) for only Cloud Tasks calls. As far as I can tell, there is no set of IPs I could whitelist so I’m wondering if there is another way to make it behave as if it’s happening in an internal network. Alternatives and/or suggestions welcome.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#token --> Secure your endpoint with authentication and only allow the Cloud tasks Service account. Does that work for you?

Comment: @dishantmakwana, the question already mentions this part.

Comment: There is a feature request for something like this over [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/145393268), but at the moment your best bet would be to follow documentation and use the tokens to secure your requests.